# Opposites can attract

Tags: riddle, wordplay

rested my Head on me leg and heaved a sigh of Relief.
Asked the guy a Question I Didn't Understand.
climbed A Hill and saw a Battered Cowboy.
Then, decided to take a dip in the Pool.

> I may not like cats very much, but I can't say this is any better: ___________

To what am I referring?

Notes:

> It looks like some people are getting closer to a solution, so let me drop another hint: The most polar of opposites is a hypocrisy. And, in a way, the solutions are a form of hypocrisy, if you compare them to the title of this puzzle. ;)

Hint

> the Last Solution is a Cluster Of Words (see comments for details)

Comment: might need to know some history for part of it.

Comment: I know I said that opposites attract, but remember that even protons and neutrons have something in common: a charge. It just **changes based off your perspective.**

Comment: check the edit log if you're still hung up about how to read the riddle, and read the comment above if you're stuck on what to do after you've read it.

Comment: Tharquid P. Bach, the lesser-known Bach child

Comment: @question_asker Uhh. Hmmm. While I want to give you the answer because I can't say I've even heard of the guy before, and he must not have been that great, that is not the answer I am looking for. -uses force to steer puzzle back to proper direction-

Comment: Nyk... Nyk I made that name it. It's fake. I just used your capital letters to the best of my ability

Comment: right...anyways, I'm bored so I'mma be blunt with y'all: the capitalized **words** are important, not the capitalized **letters**.

Comment: Oh. OK. I was just having fun in the comments. Sorry.

Comment: Well that blows my theory... With 13 capital letters, I thought it would relate to the first 13 colonies.  10 of them match up with the names of the capitals for the colonies, but Q, U and I do not (not even the original cities in the case where the capital has since moved)  With Kingston being the original capital of New York, it shoots that idea down.

Comment: ...never even thought of that. Might be useful later on, though! (for another puzzle, I mean)

Comment: what IS a portmanteau? Is it a single word, or a bunch of words grouped together as one?

Comment: According to wikipedia, it's a single word, such as 'smog' or 'motel'.

Comment: ... ... ... that was supposed to be a rhetorical question. Read the hint properly.

Comment: "You better duck down the alley way
Lookin' for a new friend
A man in a coon-skin cap
In a pig pen
Wants eleven dollar bills
You only got ten."  To what was Dylan referring?

Comment: wait..what the...no idea.

Comment: @HughMeyers: great. Perhaps there should be a bot to select Dylan lyrics and post them here with a riddle tag. Would be totally plausible.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**
For line 3 I now think the clue is (using previous conclusions mentioned below):

> Crestfallen.
>  The top of a hill is the crest, and a battered cowboy is a fallen soldier. This also fits the title since crest in the top/highest, and fallen implies the bottom/lower

For Line 1 I think it could be:

> Either Foreground or Foreclosure
>  Foreground comes from fore being the head, and Relief being ground as in grounding yourself. These are opposites in the sense that fore is the top and ground is the bottom
>  Foreclosure comes from fore being the head, and closure being a form of relief. I'm not entirely sure how these two are opposites though

---

**(Old progress, pointed out to be wrong by OP)**

This is only a partial answer as I have only somewhat deciphered what lines 1 and 3 are about. I bolded the capitalized words since OP mentioned that they were important. I am more certain of line 3 than line 1.

Line 1:

> rested my **Head** on me leg and heaved a sigh of **Relief**

What I think it means:

> I believe it has something to do with a pain relief drug such as acetaminophen or ibuprofen (or a brand name of those i.e. Tylenol, Advil) as head and relief together usually signify headache relief and OP mentioned words grouped together

Line 3:

> climbed **A Hill** and saw a **Battered Cowboy**.

What I think it means:

> OP metioned you may need to know some history to answer the question so this leads me to believe this clue is about Theodore Roosevelt and the Rough Riders and their battle on Kettle Hill. A Hill referring to Kettle Hill, the most famous of the rough rider battle grounds. Battered --> Rough, Cowboy --> Rider is why I think Battered Cowboy is about the Rough Riders.

Hopefully these are correct and will help someone put the all the puzzle pieces together for the final solution

Comment: Also, Line 1 is a little off. Remember that these are not references, but opposites that I am searching for. My advice would be this: Don't think about the puzzle as a whole and what it could mean, but rather treat each and every part separately and individually.

Comment: Line 3's interpretation is close, but not quite. Hint: The name is kind of archaic, isn't it? I wonder if there's a shorter and more modern version of it out there...something that can be combined with something on A Hill to form a single word...

Comment: @Nyk232 is line 3 rooted? Root being part of a tree, ted being short for theodore. (I wasn't sure if I should comment this or put it in my answer)

Comment: Nope. The first part is related to a hill or mountain, something Teddy might have stepped up on to when viewing the battle unfold beneath his feet. (hint: may refer to the action as well)

Comment: @Nyk232 I made an update to my answer a little while back, could you check it out to see if I am on the right track?

Comment: Crest is right, but I am referring to a particular Battered Cowboy, one who had a battle on a notable hill...

Comment: For Line 1: remember that I mentioned opposites, which is true. When you rest your head on something, what is the part of your head that is ACTUALLY resting on that surface? What part of your body would be touching your knee(leg)? Also, apply the logic you used to get FORE to figure out the second part of Line 1, as well.